# Cannot install gem with Chef for an RVM gemset

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rvm, chef-infra

I am simply trying to install passenger for nginx but installing the passenger gem fails. Here's what I have in my recipe:

```
rvm_gem "passenger" do
  ruby_string "ruby-1.9.3-p194@env"
  action      :install
end

# install nginx for rails
execute "passenger_module1" do
  user "#{node[:user][:name]}"
  environment ({'HOME' => "/home/#{node[:user][:name]}"})
  command "rvmsudo passenger-install-nginx-module --auto | bash"
  action :run
end
```

Here's the Error message:

```
[2012-12-10T01:05:52+00:00] FATAL: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: rvm_gem[passenger] (main::default line 127) had an error: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: Expected process to exit with [0], but received '1'
---- Begin output of bash -c "source /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh && rvm version | cut -d ' ' -f 2" ----
STDOUT: 
STDERR: bash: /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh: No such file or directory
---- End output of bash -c "source /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh && rvm version | cut -d ' ' -f 2" ----
Ran bash -c "source /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh && rvm version | cut -d ' ' -f 2" returned 1
```

Comment: What version of Chef are you using? This is critical information when looking at these issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any issues with your Chef recipe fragment.  The error message indicates that the execution of rvm in the shell is failing, because /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh does not exist.

This makes me think that you may not have rvm installed on this node. Did you install rvm on the node?

If you did, did you do it in a way that made it immediately available for use in your Chef run?